# Can an electric transmission line of 40075 Kilometers exist?

Tags: electricity, power-sources

How long an electric transmission line will be? How much volts of AC need to transmit that far? How much will be the loss of power during transmission?

Comment: Need to know line resistance. Is this a superconducting line with none at all, or a standard power line?

Comment: This seems like a straightforward question for Electrical Engineering SE. In fact, it seems a lot like [this one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125737/), which has answers complete with references and additional learning links.

Comment: There seems to be something missing here. What planet would you want to build this on?  I note that, if you Google for circ. of the Earth, the number that pops up is 40,075 km.  After a few 1000 km you start to really not want AC because of antenna losses. So you switch to DC, a technology that has advanced the last couple decades.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better asked and answered on another SE forum https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/125737/

Comment: @puppetsock: Yes, see HVDC power transmission: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-voltage_direct_current  A notable example in the US is the Pacific DC Intertie, connecting Columbia River hydroelectric dams with Southern California: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_DC_Intertie

Comment: I ask because I had an idea how to connect europe or america with Sahara desert to have power

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically, yes. However using current tech I don't think it would be particularly useful.

using a starting voltage of 100KV and a copper cable size of 300m2/600kcmil. With a current draw of just 10amps the voltage drop would be 45% across the specified distance.

You would need to drastically increase your cable size or use a super conductor for this to be realistically feasible.

Comment: We can optimize power loss using multiple phases, multiple conductors and higher voltage, but for any practical application, the result would be still not so great [voltage drop calculator](https://www.calculator.net/voltage-drop-calculator.html?material=copper&wiresize=0.05671&voltage=100000&phase=ac3&noofconductor=4&distance=40075&distanceunit=kilometers&amperes=10&x=75&y=24)

Comment: @Alexander That voltage drop calculator seems to be only the resistance part.  That will be the part you can't remove by going to AC. For AC you need to calculate the radiation loss. When the cable becomes long compared to 1/4 wavelength at 60 Hz, you start to get an efficient antenna.  So someplace around 1300 km you start to need to go DC..